# Prove that stopped discrete time nonnegative supermartingales are uniformly integrable

Tags: stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I came across this [note](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~spieksma/colleges/sp-master/Ch2.pdf) online. On page 40 theorem 2.2.18, it seems to suggest that any stopped discrete time nonnegative supermartingale is uniformly integrable and I cannot figure out why. To be more precise, let $\{X_{n}\}_{\mathbb{N}}$ be a discrete time nonnegative supermartingale and $T$ be a stopping time. Prove that the process $\{X_{T\land n}\}_{\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the proof of Theorem 2.2.18 in the note you link to, it is in fact claimed that $\{X_k\}$ stopped at the *bounded* stopping time $T\wedge n$ ($n$ fixed) is uniformly integrable. That is, the sequence $\{X_{T\wedge n\wedge k}\}_{k\ge 0}$ is uniformly integrable. This is clear because the sequence in question comprises finitely many integrable random variables.

Comment: I see. Now it makes much more sense. Thank you!