# Stopped uniformly integrable process in discrete time is uniformly integrable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, uniform-integrability

I'm studying for work the book: "Stochastic Calculus and Application"  by Choen and Elliot 2 ed.  In section $4.2$ (pg. 91) it states the **discrete** version of the **Optional Stopping Theorem** for bounded Stopping time:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a filtered probability space with filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Given that $S$ is a stopping time with respect to the filtation It defines the random Variable

$X_S: \omega\mapsto X_{S(\omega)}(\omega) $

and it defines the the stopped process:

$\{X^S_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = \{X_{\min\{S,n\}}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $.

*Suppose that $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an 
$\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}-$supermartingale.  If $S$ and $T$ are bounded
$\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}-$stopping times and $S\leq T$ a.s., then $E[X_T |\mathcal{F}_S] \leq X_S$ a.s.*

As corollary of the theorem the book states: that if $S$ is a bounded stopping time then:

1) If $X$ is a super-martingale, so is $X^S$.

2) If $X$ is a sub-martingale, so is $X^S$.

3) If $X$ is a martingale, so is $X^S$.

4) If $X$ is a uniformly integrable, so is $X^S$.

I've understood the theorem and I succeed in proving the points 1,2 and 3 but I can't prove point 4 of the corollary. I need some extra hypothesis to start the proof for example that $X$ is a super-martingale (as in [Prove that stopped discrete time nonnegative supermartingales are uniformly integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609530/prove-that-stopped-discrete-time-nonnegative-supermartingales-are-uniformly-inte)). AmI missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the definition of uniform intergablity. Suppose $\tau \leq N$. Then $E|X_{\tau \wedge n}|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n}| >\Delta }\}$ $\leq E|X_n|I_{\{ \tau \geq nX_{\tau \wedge n >\Delta }\}}$ $+E(|X_1|+|X_2|+...+|X_N|) I_{\{{\tau <n,Y>\Delta }\}}$ where $Y=|X_1|+|X_2|+...+|X_N|$ The first term does not exceed $E|X_n|I_{\{|X_n| >\Delta\}}$. In the second term note that $P(Y >\Delta ) \to 0$ as $\Delta \to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand the first inequality.

Comment: Ok. but on the set $\{ \tau \leq n \}$ I Think that $X_{ \tau \wedge n}=X_{\tau }$

Comment: @SimoneP There were some typos. I hope it is alright now.

Comment: Of course, I am writing $\tau$ for your stopping time $S$.

Comment: OK. Where do you use the Optional Stopping Theorem?

Comment: No. need for OST or any other theorem. For a bounded stopping time the result follows from definitions.

Comment: SO the book is misleading?

Comment: $E|X_{\tau \wedge n}|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n}| >\Delta\ }  = $                      $E|X_n|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n}| >\Delta , \tau \geq n\} +$                                       $ E|X_{\tau}|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n ,\tau <n}| >\Delta\} $

Comment: OST is required for the other properties. It is not required for 4).

Comment: $E|X_{\tau \wedge n}|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n}| >\Delta\} }$= 
$E|X_{n}|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n}| >\Delta , \tau \geq n\}} $+
$E|X_{\tau}|I_{\{|X_{\tau \wedge n}| >\Delta , \tau < n\}} \leq $ 
$E|X_{n}|I_{\{|X_{n}| >\Delta , \tau \geq n\}} $+
$E|X_{\tau}|I_{\{|X_{\tau}| >\Delta , \tau < n\}} \leq $
$E|X_{n}|I_{\{|X_{n}| >\Delta \}} + $
$\sup_{n\leq N} E|X_{n}|I_{\{|X_n| >\Delta \}} $. the left side goes to zero by Hypothesis of uniform integrability. Right?

Comment: I re-write your answer to see if I' ve understood.

Comment: I'm waiting for your comment to accept your answer.

Comment: @SimoneP I think you have understood the proof.